# Origin of the 'Three Rules of Work', popularly attributed to Einstein

Tags: etymology, phrase-origin

Does anyone know where the 'Three rules of work' is from?

> Out of clutter, find simplicity. From discord, find harmony. In the middle of difficulty, lies opportunity

Internet quote sites such as [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/312724-out-of-clutter-find-simplicity-from-discord-find-harmony-in) and [Quote Master](https://www.quotemaster.org/q437b620f19ede5bbc63e97f784098f55) attribute Einstein, but don't give a primary source as to where he said it. Is it really an Einstein quote, and if not who said it?

Comment: If it's from Einstein, it's from Einstein. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: It appears it is not a direct quote from Einstein. John Archibald Wheeler said it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be by John Archibald Wheeler:

> “Einstein's Three Rules of Work: 1) Out of clutter find simplicity; 2)
> From discord find harmony; 3) In the middle of difficulty lies
> opportunity.”

[Interview in Cosmic Search, Vol. 1, No. 4 (Fall 1979). Sometimes this quote is attributed to Albert Einstein himself.]

Source: [izQuotes.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20180126004620/http://izquotes.com/quote/327278)

Comment: Thanks for the quote. I hadn't come across it before. I must read more.